# How to check which <a> tag has been clicked from jsp on a servlet

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp page with anchor below:

```
<a href ="servletpage"> Delete   <a/>
<a href = "servletpage"> Update<a/>
```

As a result of what link the user clicks, either an update or delete will be called from the servlet. Does anyone know how we can perform the above? I also need to send the attributes which are in my form to the servlet - without using submit button from my form as the submit button is already redirecting to a servlet performing add record operation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need different methods to handle two actions.

```
<a href="servlet?action='delete'"> Delete</a>
<a href="servlet?action='update'"> Update</a>
```

Something like this.

Hope this helps!